# how to prevent python json.loads() to decoding characters unnecessarily

Tags: python, json

I have a file that has:

```
 {
  "name": "HOSTNAME_HTTP",
  "description": "Custom hostname for http service route.  Leave blank for default hostname, e.g.: \u003capplication-name\u003e-\u003cproject\u003e.\u003cdefault-domain-suffix\u003e" 
 }
```

when I open the file using:

```
 with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

I pass this to json.loads and the content in data is replaced with:

```
  <application>...</application>
```

How can I prevent python json.loads from messing with the encoding in the content?

Comment: What do you mean by adding/deleting/modifying nodes? It isn't really clear what you are trying to achieve. If you're passing it a string and not a json object... then why are you trying to parse that with json?

Comment: I have edited the question - the problem could be better stated as that I need the content to be used verbatim ie no encoding / decoding is expected.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: The latest version. I think 3.8.1

Comment: try `with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding='ascii') as file` maybe?

Comment: The file you posted isn’t in JSON format - could you post the actual format you’re reading? Strings in JSON may legally contain escaped characters which are treated *identically* to their regular equivalents - e.g. \u003c is indistinguishable from < in the JSON encoding. If you’re trying to treat them differently you might have to roll your own decoder.

Comment: It might also help if you describe your whole problem - why do you need to keep the \u003c in the string? For example, if it’s for HTML escaping or some other escaping scheme, Python has separate libraries for that.

Comment: This is a x-y problem, because you are trying to use the json module to parse something that is not properly json encoded. Don't (1). Just go back one step and wonder what you *actually* want to produce and what is your original input. (1) It is probably possible to tweak a JSONDecoder to do what you ask, but that would end in an ugly and hard to maintain solution.

Comment: This is the openshift deployment template which has been created by someone else. This particular line with unicode is also written by someone else. All I am trying to do is to manipulate some other part without affecting the existing code. So I have to leave the existing parts intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a workaround like this to escape the unicode sequences:

```py
>>> obj = json.loads(data.replace('\\', '\\\\'))
>>> obj
{'name': 'HOSTNAME_HTTP',
 'description': 'Custom hostname for http service route.  Leave blank for default hostname, e.g.: \\u003capplication-name\\u003e-\\u003cproject\\u003e.\\u003cdefault-domain-suffix\\u003e'}
```

And then when you're done modifying:

```py
>>> print(json.dumps(obj).replace('\\\\', '\\'))
{"name": "HOSTNAME_HTTP", "description": "Custom hostname for http service route.  Leave blank for default hostname, e.g.: \u003capplication-name\u003e-\u003cproject\u003e.\u003cdefault-domain-suffix\u003e"}
```

If you expect other backslashes in the file, it would be safer to use regular expressions:

```py
import re

from_pattern = re.compile(r'(\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})')
to_pattern = re.compile(r'\\(\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})')

def from_json_escaped(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return json.loads(from_pattern.sub(r'\\\1', f.read()))

def to_json_escaped(path, obj):
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(to_pattern.sub(r'\1', json.dumps(obj)))
```

Comment: sounds like a good approach. I have a question: why we need (\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}) instead of just \\u only?

Comment: @user1539343 It’s not strictly necessary if your data doesn’t contain any other strings starting with `\u`, but since we know the exact format of unicode escape sequences we might as well use it to be on the safe side.

Comment: Perfect! Everything is working as expected; and you are right: we need to use the format "r'(\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})'" otherwise python converts something else like the quotes. Please post this as answer so that I can mark this as such.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
import json
from json.decoder import JSONDecoder

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()    
    data_without_dump = '{"data":\"' + data + '\"}'

    datum_dump = json.dumps(data) 
    datum = '{"data": ' + datum_dump + '}'
    datum_load = json.loads(datum)

    datum_load_without_dump = json.loads(data_without_dump)


print(datum_dump)
print(datum)
print(datum_load["data"])
print(datum_load_without_dump["data"])
print(type(datum_dump), type(datum), type(datum_load))
```

Output:

```
"\\u003capplication\\u003e.....\\u003c/application\\u003e"
{"data": "\\u003capplication\\u003e.....\\u003c/application\\u003e"}
\u003capplication\u003e.....\u003c/application\u003e
<application>.....</application>
<class 'str'> <class 'str'> <class 'dict'>
```

My reasoning:

`json.loads` : Deserialize a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document to a Python object.
`json.dumps` : Serialize obj to a JSON formatted str.

So, using them in cascading gets the desired result.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense to me. datum_load[‘data’] is going to be identical to the string that was loaded from the file - that’s what dumps/loads would achieve. I don’t see how this changes anything.

Comment: As the question asked to prevent encoding of `\u003c` to `<`. So, this does it? Can you please elaborate your point.

Comment: What I’m trying to say is that “data = file.read()” already loads the data with the \u003c, *if you assume that’s the input format*. The JSON stuff you’re doing here is entirely superfluous and is not adding anything.

Comment: I get your point but what I found was `json.load ` decodes the encoding. Please see the edit in my answer.